# An error in implementing regex function on a list

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, nlp-question-answering

I was trying to implement a regex on a list of grammar tags in python, for finding the tense form of the list of grammar. And I wrote the following code to implement it.

Data preprocessing:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
import nltk

text = "He will have been doing his homework." 

tokenized = word_tokenize(text)
tagged = pos_tag(tokenized)
tags = []
for i in range(len(tagged)):
    t = tagged[i]
    tags.append(t[1])
print(tags)
```

regex formula i.e. to be implemented

```
grammar = r"""
Future_Perfect_Continuous: {<MD><VB><VBN><VBG>}
Future_Continuous:         {<MD><VB><VBG>}
Future_Perfect:            {<MD><VB><VBN>}
Past_Perfect_Continuous:   {<VBD><VBN><VBG>}
Present_Perfect_Continuous:{<VBP|VBZ><VBN><VBG>}
Future_Indefinite:         {<MD><VB>}
Past_Continuous:           {<VBD><VBG>}
Past_Perfect:              {<VBD><VBN>}
Present_Continuous:        {<VBZ|VBP><VBG>}
Present_Perfect:           {<VBZ|VBP><VBN>}
Past_Indefinite:           {<VBD>}
Present_Indefinite:        {<VBZ>|<VBP>}
```

Function to implement the regex on the list `tags`

```
def check_grammar(grammar, tags):
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    result = cp.parse(tags)
    print(result)
    result.draw()
 
check_grammar(grammar, tags)
```

But it returned an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samar/Desktop/twitter_tense/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    check_grammar(grammar, tags)
  File "/home/samar/Desktop/twitter_tense/main.py", line 31, in check_grammar
    result = cp.parse(tags)
  File "/home/samar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 1276, in parse
    chunk_struct = parser.parse(chunk_struct, trace=trace)
  File "/home/samar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 1083, in parse
    chunkstr = ChunkString(chunk_struct)
  File "/home/samar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 95, in __init__
    tags = [self._tag(tok) for tok in self._pieces]
  File "/home/samar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 95, in <listcomp>
    tags = [self._tag(tok) for tok in self._pieces]
  File "/home/samar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 105, in _tag
    raise ValueError("chunk structures must contain tagged " "tokens or trees")
ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to the `cp.parse()` function expects each of the tokens in your sentence to be tagged, however, the `tags` list you created only contains the tags but not the tokens as well, hence your `ValueError`. The solution is to instead pass the output from the `pos_tag()` call (i.e. `tagged`) to your `check_grammar` call (see below).

### Solution

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
import nltk

text = "He will have been doing his homework." 
tokenized = word_tokenize(text)
tagged = pos_tag(tokenized)
print(tagged)
# Output
>>> [('He', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('have', 'VB'), ('been', 'VBN'), ('doing', 'VBG'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('homework', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]

my_grammar = r"""
Future_Perfect_Continuous: {<MD><VB><VBN><VBG>}
Future_Continuous:         {<MD><VB><VBG>}
Future_Perfect:            {<MD><VB><VBN>}
Past_Perfect_Continuous:   {<VBD><VBN><VBG>}
Present_Perfect_Continuous:{<VBP|VBZ><VBN><VBG>}
Future_Indefinite:         {<MD><VB>}
Past_Continuous:           {<VBD><VBG>}
Past_Perfect:              {<VBD><VBN>}
Present_Continuous:        {<VBZ|VBP><VBG>}
Present_Perfect:           {<VBZ|VBP><VBN>}
Past_Indefinite:           {<VBD>}
Present_Indefinite:        {<VBZ>|<VBP>}"""


def check_grammar(grammar, tags):
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    result = cp.parse(tags)
    print(result)
    result.draw()


check_grammar(my_grammar, tagged)
```

### Output

```
>>> (S
>>>   He/PRP
>>>   (Future_Perfect_Continuous will/MD have/VB been/VBN doing/VBG)
>>>   his/PRP$
>>>   homework/NN
>>>   ./.)
```

[image: Parse tree result]

Comment: I have a query regarding NLP model, can you please help me?

Comment: @SamarPratapSingh You're welcome! If its programming related you can make another post on stackoverflow.com and I can try to help. Otherwise, if it's about NLP models more generally, datascience.stackexchange.com would be a better option.

Comment: Can i please contact you via LinkedIn, or whatsapp, actually I need an advice.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115497/recommendations-of-nlp-for-classifying-sentance-into-tense-forms

Comment: Here is the issue :-)